# Data table for excel vba?

Tags: excel, datatable, vba

I have thousands of search results to show in Excel VBA application. But seems like there's no such component which works like data table. I think binding the search results to thousands of excel rows is the closest thing I can do.

Do VBA supports any component like that? Is there anyway I can get a data table alike component with scroll bar?

Comment: Consider creating a **ListBox** with a scroll bar and populating that ListBox with your search results.

Comment: Thanks. But how about columns? I have at least 10 columns to be displayed..

Comment: What does a data table give you that an Excel worksheet does not?

Comment: User can always see search box and button without having to freeze top rows. And less work to bind or clear table.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a really simple example using only two columns, **A & B**

We use column **D** as a "helper" column concatenating columns **A & B**

Running this macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
    ActiveSheet.ListBoxes.Add(332.25, 62.25, 242.25, 120).Select
    s = Selection.Name
    MsgBox s
    ActiveSheet.Shapes(s).Select
    With Selection
        .ListFillRange = "$D$1:$D$100"
        .LinkedCell = "$Z$1"
        .MultiSelect = xlNone
        .Display3DShading = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Produces::

[image]

NOTE:

I used in **D1**:

```
=A1 & B1
```

and copied down